# Callback is to promise as watch is to ... habit?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I assume everyone knows that a Promise is a data-structure that largely replaces callback as the way to handle asynchrony in Javascript.  A Promise can chained, cached, and otherwise manipulated in useful ways.

The Angular $watch function is vital to the functioning of Angular but it takes a callback and has the same shortfalls as callbacks generally.  Using a Promise instead would not appropriate because intrinsic to a Promise is the fact it is fulfilled or canceled exactly once.

So I built an analogous structure I have provisionally named a `Habit`.  A Habit is much like a Promise.  You construct it with a scope and a watch-expression.  Instead of `then()` it has an `on()`, which is called with a function. That function will be called whenever the watch-expression changes in the scope.

The return value of the `on()` is a new Habit, which will be fired with the return value of the function.  If that return value is a Promise, it will fire when the Promise is fulfilled.

For example,

```
  util.habit(scope, "user_id")
    .on(function(user_id) {
          return $.ajax('/users/' + user_id)
                  .then(function(user) {
                     return user.name;
                  });
    });
```

would create a Habit that fires whenever the user_id changes in the scope and invokes its on-functions with the new user's name.

My question are

1. Is this brilliant, obvious, old-hat, or stupid?
2. Why?

Comment: I have no idea why this was closed. I'm voting to reopen. It's a legitimate question and has nothing to do with code-review.

Comment: Also - observable - it's an observable. More accurately - a _promise_ is a to a _value_ as an _iterable_ is to an _observable_. When you have a property that changes and you watch it - you're actually watching an _asynchronous iteration_ of values - basically composing getters for side effects. Basically https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Lang-NEXT/Lang-NEXT-2014/Keynote-Duality

Comment: On topic, I do like the idea of how you are abstracting away the access to scope as a generic thing, but I'm not sure this is a totally great idea; ideally speaking, a service does not have access to a scope, which means the only place this would happen is a controller/filter (possibly directive link). Do these places need the (potentially confusing) abstraction around `$scope.$watch`? I don't think so, personally.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- like Promises, Habits are a lot more FP than [Observers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). They are in the same ecological niche, but Observers cannot be chained or cached.

Comment: Nonono, I'm talking about __Observables__ - as in https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS

Comment: @DanPantry -- I use $scope in the standard factory for a Habit, but you could make and use one manually, just as the most common factory for a Promise is $http, but you can make one with $q.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- ah, I thought you mean a GoF Observer/Observable.  In a Reactive programming model, these are Reactors, because they can participate in a chain reaction (at least in the Var/Rx/Obs version of Reactive [I am used to](https://github.com/lihaoyi/scala.rx)).

Comment: Well, Erik Meijer is call them Observable and he wrote Rx and first understood the duality of observables and iterables - so I think I'm good with Observable :) if you check out RxJS I'm sure you'll find it very similar to what you describe in your question. A changing value and an iterable are the same thing - an iterable is a multi-value getter, yielding the next value whenever it changes :) The lecture I linked to above explains this :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- the Rx/Obs distinction is equivalent to the map/forEach distinction: an Rx's only purpose is to map one change (or group of changes) into another with no side-effects; an Obs only has side-effects.  Because Habits are simplified Observables, they implement both `map()` and `forEach()` together as `on()` (and right now, don't implement `filter()` at all).  Do I really want to watch a lecture with both "PHP" and "MSDN" on the first page?

Comment: Yes, you do. Would it make you feel better if I said the author has made a significant contribution to Haskell?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- a little, but the first thing out of his mouth was "So I have my new Windows phone..."

Comment: It's irony :) keep watching the whole thing is full of Microsoft bashing - I'll delete my comments shortly and if no one does soon- will post an answer

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum -- full of Microsoft bashing?  Oh, I am definitely watching it now!  (I am going to pretend he said "So I have my new Windows phone... oh, wait, I forgot: I have an iPhone, *just like everyone else!*")

Comment: @Malvolio That is practically what he said. Did you literally stop watching after two seconds? Also, an overpriced, excessively restrictive device that can't multitask, whose main distinguishing feature is "being shiny" is good, while anything Microsoft makes is automatically bad? Ok...

Comment: @Malvolio  Also, _"Do I really want to watch a lecture with both "PHP" and "MSDN" on the first page?"_ Only if you're interested in learning something from an industry expert in the topic you're asking about. It seems your primary focus is asking open-ended questions, reinventing the wheel, and dismissing people out of hand based on the phone you think they have, so no need to watch that video.

Comment: @JLRishe -- I don't know if your Windows phone has a dictionary, but if it does, bring it up and type j-o-k-e and hit enter or submit or whatever and see what happens.

Comment: @Malvolio My phone is a crappy 4 year old Android made by NEC, and it doesn't have a dictionary, so I guess I'll never know what a joke is.

Comment: @JLRishe -- you probably won't, but don't blame the phone.  :-)